# Transpositions wrt the energy and usual norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $^\dagger$ denote transposition w.r.t. the usual norm $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $^*$ denote transposition w.r.t. the energy norm $(\cdot,\cdot)_A$ defined for symmetric $A$: $(u,v)_A=(Au,v)=(u,Av)$.

If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, how can I show that $(BA)^*=B^\dagger A^\dagger$?

My solution: $(BA)^*$ is the matrix s.t. $((BA)Au,v)=(Au,(BA)^*v)\forall u,v.$ We know $(Au,v)=(u,Av)\Rightarrow (AAu,v)=(Au,Av)\Rightarrow (BAAu,v)=(Au,B^TAv)
\forall u,v$. So $B^TA=(BA)^*$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Is the $A$ in $(BA)^*$ the same $A$ as is used to define the energy norm?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably, you should have $(u,v)_A = (Au,v) = (u,A^\dagger v)$, unless $A$ is supposed to be Hermitian.  If $A$ is Hermitian, then $A^\dagger = A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that $C = D^*$ if for any vectors $u,v$, we have $(Cu,v)_A = (u,Dv)_A$.

With that in mind: for any vectors $u,v$ in our Hilbert space, we have
$$
((BA)u,v)_A = (ABAu,v) = (BAu,A^\dagger v) = (Au,B^\dagger A^\dagger v) = (u,B^\dagger A^\dagger v)_A
$$
thus we have reached the desired conclusion.